# a savings -- is that even grammatical?

Tags: grammatical-number

Example:

> In the second example using the char pointer, we still have the string constant, requiring 5 bytes of storage, but we do not have to reserve another 5 bytes of storage for an array to which this constant can be copied. There is no char array. Therefore, the string data storage requirements of this program are half that of the previous program. Of course, the pointer itself requires 2 bytes of storage, but this still represents **a savings of 3 bytes**.

Do you think that kind of usage of the word *savings* is grammatically correct? If you try and look up the word *savings* in the dictionary, nowhere will there be a mention that *savings* can be used as a singular noun. What gives?

Comment: I think it trickles into written language from colloquial use.  "How does one say that we're reduce the amount of memory spent on something?" -- "Use the word *savings* somehow, duh", and then the writer/speaker associates each act of *saving* something (money, memory, time) with that word...

Comment: IOW, "a savings of ..." = "a single act of saving ..."

Comment: To say that they are using 'savings' as a singular noun is a bit of a misnomer. It is still acting as a verb. It is describing that a savings or reduction in use of memory was in the amount of 3 bytes. I think it is simply a more efficient way to say "but this still represents less utilization of memory in the amount of 3 bytes"

Comment: Uhm... "*but this still represents less utilization of memory*" is not grammatical.  The verb '*represents*' needs a direct object.  In your text, '*utilization*' seems to be that object.  You are allowed to define it with an adjective, but not with an adverb ("*less*" is no longer in use as an adjective, methinks).  Did you mean something like "*smaller*" or "*frugal*", maybe?

Comment: @VictorBazarov *Less*, is a quantifier and may be employed as a determiner: *George has less money than Martha*.

Comment: @StoneyB: No doubt, no doubt.  Where is the "than" in that sentence?  Implied?  I don't buy it.

Comment: Just doesn't sound natural "less utilization", "more utilization".  Just doesn't.  Sorry.

Comment: @VictorBazarov The *than* complement can always be omitted if it is recoverable from context. *Martha has $1000. George has less money, but more charm.* *A charptr uses less memory [than a charray].* ... I don't much care for *less utilization* myself, but it's a problem with *utilization*, not with *less*.

Comment: Well, when one has a hole in a door it could be the problem with the hole or with the door, but it's still a problem.  "Less utilization" is not working.  I recommended to replace "less" and you started giving counter-examples of its validity.  It is **not valid** here.  Period.

Comment: @VictorBazarov All I objected to was your characterization of *less* as an adverb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Savings* as subject of a singular verb is very common in US English; you will find it, for instance, in the online [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/saving) if you select 'American English':

> 3. (*[often pl., with sing. v.]*) any reduction in expense, time, labor, etc.   ⇒ *a saving( s) of 10% is effected*

Comment: I accept the dictionary authority of its use in American English, but in British English "a savings of 10%" looks semi-literate. In BrE "savings" can be used as an adjectival noun, for example in "a savings account", i.e. a bank account that pays interest on the money deposited, and may have restrictions on withdrawing money on demand etc, as opposed to "a current account" which does not pay interest and has no restrictions.